# Communication between Blazor Components using EventCallback for Checkboxes

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

The below references WeatherForecast which is included in the Blazor templates however it's a proof of concept for a real project.

Okay, I have a component WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelect.razor which allows the user to select whether they want to view detailed forecasts.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="@WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelection.Detailed" @onchange="ChangeSelection" /> Display detailed forecast
```

The code for this component is as follows

```
using BlazorPlayground.ServerSide.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlazorPlayground.ServerSide.Components
{
    public partial class WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelect
    {        
        [Parameter]
        public WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelection WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelection { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public EventCallback<WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelection> WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelectionChanged { get; set; }

        protected void HandleInvalidSubmit()
        {

        }

        protected void HandleValidSubmit()
        {

        }

        protected void OnParamatersSet()
        {

        }

        private async Task ChangeSelection()
        {
            if (WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelection.Detailed == false)
            {
                WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelection.Detailed = true;
            }
            else
            {
                WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelection.Detailed = false;
            }

            await WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelectionChanged.InvokeAsync(WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelection);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a second component WeatherForecastDataGrid.razor which displays one of two tables dependant on the option selected.

```
@if (WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelection.Detailed)
{
    <MudTable Items="@Data" Dense="false" Hover="true" Bordered="false" Striped="true" SortLabel="Sort by">
        <ToolBarContent>
            <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">7 Day Forecast</MudText>
        </ToolBarContent>
        <HeaderContent>
            <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel InitialDirection="SortDirection.Descending" SortBy="new Func<WeatherForecast, object>(x => x.Date)">Date</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
            <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<WeatherForecast, object>(x => x.TemperatureC)">Temperature C</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
            <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<WeatherForecast, object>(x => x.TemperatureF)">Temperature F</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
            <MudTh>Summary</MudTh>
        </HeaderContent>
        <RowTemplate>
            <MudTd DataLabel="Date">@context.Date.ToShortDateString()</MudTd>
            <MudTd DataLabel="Temperature C">@context.TemperatureC</MudTd>
            <MudTd DataLabel="Temperature F">@context.TemperatureF</MudTd>
            <MudTd DataLabel="Summary">@context.Summary</MudTd>
        </RowTemplate>
        <PagerContent>
            <MudTablePager />
        </PagerContent>
    </MudTable>
}
else
{
    <MudTable Items="@Data" Dense="false" Hover="true" Bordered="false" Striped="true" SortLabel="Sort by">
        <ToolBarContent>
            <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">7 Day Forecast</MudText>
        </ToolBarContent>
        <HeaderContent>
            <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel InitialDirection="SortDirection.Descending" SortBy="new Func<WeatherForecast, object>(x => x.Date)">Date</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
            <MudTh>Summary</MudTh>
        </HeaderContent>
        <RowTemplate>
            <MudTd DataLabel="Date">@context.Date.ToShortDateString()</MudTd>
            <MudTd DataLabel="Summary">@context.Summary</MudTd>
        </RowTemplate>
        <PagerContent>
            <MudTablePager />
        </PagerContent>
    </MudTable>
}
```

These two components are called from Index.razor in the below manner

```
<WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelect @bind-WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelection="@WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelection" />
    
<WeatherForecastDataGrid Data="@WeatherForecasts" WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelection="@WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelection" />
```

That all works fine and the value of WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelection.Detailed is being passed nicely to and from the components.

The first issue is that I can't work out how to do the same with InputCheckbox as in

```
<EditForm Model="@WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelection" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit" OnInvalidSubmit="@HandleInvalidSubmit" class="form">
    <InputCheckbox @bind-Value="@WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelection.Detailed"></InputCheckbox> Display detailed forecast
</EditForm>
```

In scenarios where the WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelection model had more properties  such as Basic, Summary, Detailed it would be nice to be able to efficiently pass around WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelection whenever a change was made to any of its properties as at the moment I would need to update ChangeSelection() in WeatherForecastDisplayModeSelect.razor.cs to include a parameter which helped me identify which property was being updated.

Thanks in advance.